# Electron JS app icon not showing on Windows Store

Tags: electron, windows-store-apps, electron-builder, appx

I am trying to publish my electron app to Windows store but it is showing default electron icon whereas the exe created has correct icon. Even on launching the Appx file, correct icon is showing up. How can I change the default icon of electron and put the correct icon on store?

Package JSON:

```
"build": {
"appId": "xxxx.xxxx.xxxx",
"directories": {
  "buildResources": "build"
},
"win": {
  "icon": "assets/icons/win/icon.ico",
  "target": [
    "Appx",
    "nsis"
  ]
},
"nsis": {
  "artifactName": "${productName}_Setup_${version}.${ext}",
  "installerIcon": "assets/icons/win/icon.ico"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a folder as a sub folder under `build`. `build`->`appx`(must be appx)
2. Then add some icons named as `Square44x44Logo.png`, `Square150x150Logo.png`, `StoreLogo.png`, `Wide310x150Logo.png`

I believe you can get the image resolution from the name. for `StoreLogo.png` 256*256 will be fine.

Comment: I have already tried that still electron logo is showing up. The command I am using is,
electron-windows-store --input-directory C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\unpacked\app  --output-directory C:\store --package-version 5.0.6.0 --package-name "packagename" --dev-cert C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\cer\mykey.pfx --cert-pass xxxxx --publisher CN=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  --identity-name xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --publisher-display-name "xxxxxxxxxxx"  --package-display-name "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

Comment: StoreLogo.png was 50x50 and this method worked for me. I have not installed this app but WAC warnings gone and when open Appx it is now showing my logo. submitted for certification.

Answer (score 0):

As tpikachu pointed out, you haven't correctly defined the graphical assets form your package. Doing this manually is quite tedious and error-prone.

Tools like Advanced Installer Express (free forever) handle such configurations automatically. Here is an article about how to [package an MSIX for an Electron app](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/electron-msix.html) with Advanced Installer, and another one about how to [publish your app in the MS store](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-publish-microsoft-store.html):

*p.s. I work on the team building Advanced Installer*